# How to calculate two column values on select query using MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

how to calculate two columns values in select query using mysql?

Here is my sql query

```
SELECT cusName, 
       remarks, 
       invoiceNo,
       invoiceDate, 
       total_VAT, 
       bill_tot,
       ROUND(((bill_tot - total_VAT) * 5/100),2) as vatamt,
       ROUND(bill_tot - total_VAT, 2) as exclvat                   
FROM invoices 
where invoiceDate between '2018-11-13' and '2018-11-13'
order by invoiceID;
```

In the above query i need to calculate sum value of  vatamt and exclvat as total amount and display it.Can anyone help me please to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reuse an aliased Calculated expression again inside a `SELECT` clause. They can be reused only in either `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, `HAVING` clauses. You will need to specify the calculation expressions again, to calculate the `total_amount`:

```
SELECT cusName, 
       remarks, 
       invoiceNo,
       invoiceDate, 
       total_VAT, 
       bill_tot,
       ROUND((bill_tot - total_VAT) * 5/100,2) as vatamt, -- got rid of extra parentheses
       ROUND(bill_tot - total_VAT, 2) as exclvat,
       ROUND((bill_tot - total_VAT) * 5/100,2) + 
       ROUND(bill_tot - total_VAT, 2) as total_amount
FROM invoices 
where invoiceDate between '2018-11-13' and '2018-11-13'
order by invoiceID;
```

Comment: is it possible to calculate all the sum of  total_amount?

Comment: @blackwhite yes. just put this complete query under a `FROM` clause, and use `SUM()` over it. This is called derived tables. Refer this documentation for more understanding: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html

Comment: SELECT cusName, 
       remarks, 
       invoiceNo,
       invoiceDate, 
       ROUND((bill_tot - total_VAT) * 5/100,2) as vatamt,
       ROUND(bill_tot - total_VAT, 2) as exclvat,
       ROUND((bill_tot - total_VAT) * 5/100,2) + ROUND(bill_tot - total_VAT, 2) as total_amount
FROM (SELECT SUM(total_amount) AS sum_total_amount
        FROM invoices
where invoiceDate between '2018-11-13' and '2018-11-13'
order by invoiceID;

Comment: @blackwhite no. you are doing it other way around. your internal subquery should be outside instead.

Comment: i need to get total sum of three columns ie;vatamt,exclvat and total_amount

Comment: @blackwhite Do: `SELECT SUM(dt.vatamt) as total_vatamt, 
       SUM(dt.exclvat) as total_exclvat, 
       SUM(dt.vatamt + dt.exclvat) as total_total_amt 
FROM (
SELECT 
       ROUND((bill_tot - total_VAT) * 5/100,2) as vatamt,
       ROUND(bill_tot - total_VAT, 2) as exclvat
FROM invoices 
where invoiceDate between '2018-11-13' and '2018-11-13') dt`

Comment: then how will select cusName,remarks etcc...?unknown columns its showing when am selecting these columns

Comment: @blackwhite add those columns to both the select queries.

Comment: when am doing like that only first record its showing.Between 2018-11-13 i have total six records.When am calculating sum of total query.Select query  returns only first record.U have any idea why its showing wrongly?

Comment: SELECT cusName, remarks, invoiceNo,invoiceDate, 
SUM(dt.vatamt) as total_vatamt, 
SUM(dt.exclvat) as total_exclvat, 
SUM(dt.vatamt + dt.exclvat) as total_total_amt 
FROM ( SELECT ROUND((bill_tot - total_VAT) * 5/100,2) as vatamt, 
cusName, remarks, invoiceNo,invoiceDate, 
ROUND(bill_tot - total_VAT, 2) as exclvat FROM invoices where invoiceDate between '2018-11-13' and '2018-11-13') dt

Comment: @blackwhite it is very hard to understand from comments. Can you please post a new question.

Comment: After adding this query, only one  record is displaying.I dont know why

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to rank readability over performance (although the performance impact might be negligible) you could also use a wrapping query:

```
SELECT cusName, 
       remarks, 
       invoiceNo,
       invoiceDate, 
       total_VAT, 
       bill_tot,
       vatamt,
       exclvat,
       vatampt + exclvat as total_amount
FROM (
    SELECT *,
           ROUND(((bill_tot - total_VAT) * 5/100),2) as vatamt,
           ROUND(bill_tot - total_VAT, 2) as exclvat                   
    FROM invoices 
    WHERE invoiceDate between '2018-11-13' and '2018-11-13'
    ORDER BY invoiceID
) a;
```

Comment: Just a note: MySQL version 5.7 and above only optimize the Derived tables. Previous versions materialize the subquery, which reduces performance.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya am using MySQL Server 5.5.So shall i go with ur code?

Comment: @blackwhite yes in that case, my query would be most performant in terms of memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @Madhur is probably the most performant.  But in MySQL 8 we could make use of a CTE to avoid repeating common logic in the select clause:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROUND(((bill_tot - total_VAT) * 5/100),2) AS vatamt,
        ROUND(bill_tot - total_VAT, 2) AS exclvat
    FROM invoices 
    WHERE invoiceDate = '2018-11-13'
)

SELECT
   cusName, 
   remarks, 
   invoiceNo,
   invoiceDate, 
   total_VAT, 
   bill_tot,
   vatamt,
   exclvat,
   vatamt + exclvat AS total
FROM cte
ORDER BY
    invoiceID;
```

Comment: Are CTEs materialized in MySQL ? I have never used them yet. How are they different in performance terms, compared to Derived Tables.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I believe CTEs are in fact materialized in MySQL, but they are only materialized once (contrast this with a view, which may be materialized multiple times, depending on the query).

Comment: Ok. version 5.7 and onwards MySQL optimized Derived tables and Views: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/derived-table-optimization.html I believe that same should be applicable for CTEs.